# Mouse/Touchpad stuck in Ubuntu 12.04 after resuming from Suspend

Tags: mouse, touchpad, ubuntu-12.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I am a first time Ubuntu user. I put my computer in Suspend mode and then when I resumed the touchpad was not working. It was locked and the cursor was not moving at all.

So could you guys please let me know how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> type gconf-editor and press enter .
Navigate to

/desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad

Check if the touchpad_enabled box is ticked.

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting your mouse or touch pad using `xinput`. First you should know the id of your device, for doing so type in a terminal:

```
xinput
```

A list with input devices will appear, notice the id of your target device, then type

```
xinput --disable [id]
xinput --enable [id]
```

replacing `[id]` with the device ID you want to restart. It should work now.

Comment: On Kubuntu 16.04 this worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the special key combination was activated: FN+F9. I was testing this in windows and manage to activate the touchpad. I got back to Ubuntu and it also worked. It's strange that this key combination does not actually enable/disable the touchpad in Ubuntu now.